# Function to get coresponding cell content

Tags: excel

I have a sheet with a lookup table.
If text matches a value in the "A" column, I need to display the text in the "B" column.

I'm trying to use match right now, but that's where I get lost.

```
=MATCH(A1, Sheet1!$A2:$A7, 0)
```

So from here, I get an index.  I want to use that index to get the right cell address, then get the corresponding "B" column address.

Comment: Try `VLOOKUP` function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options for you:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B2:$B7, MATCH(A1, Sheet1!$A2:$A7, 0))
```

or

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet1!$A2:$B7, 2, 0)
```

Comment: excellent, thanks.  I'll mark this as the answer when the timer allows me to